# CSV reader perils - Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file and split each line into 4 different integer values via a two-dimensional array in java.

I'm using openCSV 3.8.

For the sake of simplicity, say this is the contents of the CSV file (the full file contains 306 lines just like these):

```
76,67,0,1
77,65,3,1
78,65,1,2
83,58,2,2
```

I can read the file just fine, and I can use `System.out.println` to output each single value to the console, like this:

```
76
67
0
1
77
65
3
1
78
65
1
2
85
58
2
2
```

Unfortunately with my code below, designed to enter each value into a separate array element only saves the 4 values in the last line of the file.

And here is my java code (don't mind the size of the `iaData` array, it's sized for the full CSV file):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //String outputStr = "";
        int[][] iaData = new int[306][4];
        int i = 0;
        int x = 0;

        try
        {
            //Get the CSVReader instance with specifying the delimiter to be used
             CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("haberman.data"),',');
            String [] nextLine = new String[1250];

            //Read one line at a time
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
            {           
                for (i = 0; i <= 305; i++)
                {
                    for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
                    {
                        iaData[i][x] = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[x]);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int z = 0; z <= 3; z++)
            {
            System.out.println(iaData[0][z] + "\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

With this code, I would expect my `System.out.println(iaData[0][z] + "\n");` to output the following to the console (the values in the first line of the file):

```
76

67

0

1
```

Unfortunately it's not the case, it actually outputs the following (the 4 values in the last line of the file):

```
83

58

2

2
```

What is wrong with my code such that `iaData[0][0/1/2/3]` actually outputs what I would expect to be held in `iaData[**3**][0/1/2/3]`?

Comment: Use a debugger to find it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every line, you start writing with first index i=0.
So for every line you override all information from the line before:

```
       while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
        {           
            for (i = 0; i <= 305; i++)
            {
                for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
                {
                    iaData[i][x] = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[x]);
                }
            }
        }
```

This should solve your problem:

```
int i = 0;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
        iaData[i][x] = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[x]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm glad it was as simple as me using one too many loops.

Answer (score 3):

Your current problem is that for each line you are iterating over the entire 2D array, both rowwise and columnwise.  This has the effect that only the last row will reflect the currently read line.

Instead, the row counter `i` should only be incremented *after* another line has been read from the CSV file.  Currently, you are incrementing `i` for the same line over and over again.

```
// Read one line at a time
int i = 0;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
        iaData[i][x] = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[x]);
    }
    // increment i once, after having processed a single line from the file
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various things in your code that simply don't make sense.

First, you are init'ing nextLine to probably hold 1250 lines.

```
String [] nextLine = new String[1250];
```

But then, you are pushing a **single** line into that:

```
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
```

Either you don't need the first statement; or something is wrong about the second one.

For the actual bug you are observing: it doesn't help that you keep writing the same lines 395 times, too. And that is what your code is doing; because for each line that you read, you do

```
for (i = 0; i <= 305; i++)
{
   for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
   {
      hiaData[i][x] = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[x]);
```

So you keep **overwriting** your data, instead of

```
line1
line2
...
```

you keep writing

```
line i
line i...
```

Thus, in the end, you only got your last line in there.

My recommendation: don't do all that manual size-dependent iterating yourself. Simply use

```
List<String[]> allLines = csvreader.readAll();
```

4 values, 395 lines ... that is **nothing**. Just push all of that into memory with that one call.

Meaning: the library offers you a nice abstraction that requires you **one** line of code to read all content. You choose to write 20, 30 lines of code instead. And that is the thing: the more code you write, the higher are chances to create bugs.

And finally: do not use such numbers as 305, 4, 1205 directly in your source code. If at all, use constants there. But hard-coding those values in your loops ... **very bad practice** - you have to change each and any place that deals with your input when for example 5 columns come in, instead of 4.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Re: using constants. I hadn't thought about it at this point; I was mainly trying to get the code working. That said I probably wouldn't have thought about it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 305; i++)
```

This cycle is not needed, as `reader.readNext()` will gather all the lines without the need of further help. So, this is certainly an improvement:

```
        int i = 0;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
        {           
            //for (i = 0; i <= 305; i++)
            //{
                for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
                {
                    iaData[i++][x] = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[x]);
                }
            //}
        }
```

2.

The other problem you have is that you iterate only the elements of the first element:

```
        for (int z = 0; z <= 3; z++)
        {
        System.out.println(iaData[0][z] + "\n");
        }
```

Instead:

```
        for (i = 0; i < iaData.length; i++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z <= 3; z++)
            {
            System.out.println(iaData[i][z] + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the program is going to read the whole file into an array ... is it not enough to read it into memory, and process it later?

Like so:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

public class Csv {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String string = "76,67,0,1\n" +
                "77,65,3,1\n" +
                "78,65,1,2\n" +
                "83,58,2,2";

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(string),',');
        List<String[]> lines = reader.readAll();

        for (String[] entries : lines) {
            for (String entry:  entries) {
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(entry));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Beware of memory issues and set an upper bound or process a line a time by changing the loop like so:

```
    String[] entries;
    while((entries = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        for (String entry : entries) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(entry));
        }
    }
```